# Event source removeEventlistener not removing event

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I have the following code for `EventSource` object :

```
var sse = {};(function(s){

var es = { sseinit:false },
    handle = function(){};

s.init = function (url) {
    if (es.sseinit !== undefined) {
        // condition for compilation error
        es = typeof EventSource === 'function' || typeof EventSource === 'object' ?new EventSource(url) :{};
    }
};

s.close = function () {
    if (es.sseinit === undefined) {
        es.close();
        es = { sseinit:false };
    }
};

s.addEventListener = function (name,callback) {
    handle = function(e) {
        callback(e,JSON.parse(e.data));
    };
    console.log('addEventListener :: '+name);
    es.addEventListener(name,handle);
};

s.removeEventListener = function (name) {
    if (es.sseinit !== false) {
        console.log('removeEventListener :: '+name);
        es.removeEventListener(name,handle);
    }
};}(sse));
```

When we call `es.removeEventListener` the event is not removed like `removeEventListener` does not exist for `EventSource` object.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that is a reference problem

> var sse = {}; (function(s){

```
var es = { sseinit:false };

s.init = function (url) {
    if (es.sseinit !== undefined) {
        es = typeof EventSource === 'function' || typeof EventSource === 'object' ?new EventSource(url) :{};
    }
};

s.close = function () {
    if (es.sseinit === undefined) {
        es.close();
        es = { sseinit:false };
    }
};

s.addEventListener = function (name,callback) {
    this['handle'+name] = function(e) {
        callback(e,JSON.parse(e.data));
    };
    es.addEventListener(name,this['handle'+name]);
};

s.removeEventListener = function (name) {
    if (es.sseinit !== false) {
        es.removeEventListener(name,this['handle'+name]);
    }
}; }(sse))
```

I have used "this['handle'+name]" to keep context to define handle function.